# Notice when an answer you commented on gets deleted

Tags: feature-request, comment, notifications, deleted-answers

I posted an answer to a question but it turns out I had a major error in it. Another user posted a comment pointing out the error. I agree with the comment and so I deleted the answer. For SE in general now all is fine. But for the user who made the comment, this is somewhat tricky to see. If they check their own user profile the comment is now gone so they can't easily find the question again. An easy solution for this would be that you get a notice in your inbox saying something like 'An answer you commented on was deleted'. Then the user knows his comment was resolved.

Comment: Hopefully not just that notice, but also a link.

Comment: I wonder... If you had made an @ comment to them below your answer just before you deleted the answer, would they still see reference to it in their AChIEVEMENTS tab at the top of their window?

Comment: In such cases what I usually do is post a comment like "@UserABC thanks for pointing that out, I was wrong. I will delete the answer shortly", wait a while, and then delete the answer. The rationale is that there would be sufficient time for the person to be pinged and see the response before the deletion. Far from ideal, but better than nothing, I think.